# Is there any way to remove time to compare dates only in jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 2 dates.
1st is

```
<field name="duedate" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

& second is current date
so I am doing something like this

```
<![CDATA[ $F{duedate} >= (new java.util.Date()) ? "one" : "two"]]>
```

which doesn't work if dueDate matches new `java.util.Date()`

also seems there is some problem with date format. I am using *PostgreSQL* query to get the date. 
Say query is like this

```
    <queryString>select dueDate from table1</queryString>
```

& then I get that field like this

```
<field name="duedate" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

but *PostgreSQL* dueDate o/p is of type java.sql.date

So field that I declared, will that work as util.date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.util.Date has it's own comparison methods ( compareTo(), after(), before() ), and they work in Jasper as well. So you might try something like:

```
$F{duedate}.compareTo(new java.util.Date() == 0 ? "one" : "two"
```

Another possible solution i might think of right now is to make the comparison inside the query of your report, like this:

```
SELECT
duedate as duedate,
CASE WHEN duedate == sysdate THEN "one" 
ELSE "two" END as comparison
FROM ....
```

Comment: but this does not remove time which is what I am looking for. Is there is anyway to remove time from new java.util.Date() ?

Comment: The standard way would be applying a specific format to the Date objects: 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
     
Date dateWithoutTime = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date()));

Another thing you might try, would be getting a string from this Dates (i.e: duedate.toString() and new java.util.Date().toString()) and after that getting only the interested part using the substring method. 
For example, if duedate returns the string "2012/01/20 12:05:10.321" you can do: String duedateString = duedate.substring(0, 10); then the same for the other, and compare them.

Comment: this seems more of java coding logic which I will have to perform in jrxml... can this be done in jrxml & is that advisable? I also updated the question ... please have a look

Comment: Yes, Java code does work on a jrxml as well and there is no reason why this approach shouldn't be advisable since JasperReports is build with Java. You can also work with them easily if you use a tool such as iReports, where it's edit dialogs have the option to use Java methods. You even use EL to get duedate ($F{duedate}) which implicity calls java codes. For the data type problem, you might try this: java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());